# Change hdfs write path dynamically in spark structured streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I have a spark structured streaming application which reads data from kafka and write it to hdfs. I want to change the hdfs write path dynamically based on current date, but it seems like structured streaming doesn't work that way. It just creates one folder of the date on which application was started and keep writing to same folder even if the date changes. Is there any way I can change the path dynamically based on current date?

Below is how my writestream looks like

```
 val inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
 val outPath = "maindir/sb_topic/data/loaddate="

val dswWriteStream =dfresult.writeStream
    .outputMode(outputMode) 
    .format(writeformat) 
    .option("path",outPath+inputFormat.format((new java.util.Date()).getTime())) //hdfs file write path
    .option("checkpointLocation", checkpointdir) 
    .option("maxRecordsPerFile", 999999999) 
    .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("10 minutes"))
```

Comment: Maybe good to post your answer to below and self accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solution:** I resolved this by adding current date column(e.g. 'loaddate') to parent dataframe 'dfresult' and then partitioned the writestream by that column.

```
dswWriteStream.partitionBy('loaddate')
```